# Extracting specific parts of a predictably structured string with unpredictable contents

Tags: php, regex

Ok, I have a complex problem for you guys.

I am trying to extract some values from a load of old data. It's a bunch of strings which are basically 7 parts concatenated with `||`

```
test1||keep||1:1||test||3462||7885||test
```

---

**Rules**

- Each section of the string could have any character in it, except `|` or two arrows like this `<>` (see further down) which are reserved as separators.
- Any of the sections could be empty.

e.g. In this one the first 1st, 5th and 6th sections are empty, and the 3rd contains lots of non-alphanumeric characters.

```
||keep||test's\ (o-kay?).go_od||test||||||test
```

---

**Furthermore...**

Some of the strings are made up of multiple ones of these 7 pieces, further separated with `<>`

```
test1||keep||1:1||test||3462||7885||test<>test1||keep||1:1||test||3462||7885||test<>test1||keep||1:1||test||3462||7885||test
```

Remember, any of the inner sections could be empty.

```
test54||keep||test's\ (o-kay?).go_od||test||||||<>test||keep||test545's'/.||test||||test||test
```

---

**The Goal**

Extract just the second part of every string, and put into an array. In my examples above, it is every part which has the word `keep` inside.

So for this example:

```
||keep||test's\ (o-kay?).go_od||test||||||test
```

I want to get:

```
array('keep')
```

And for this example:

```
test1||keep-me||1:1||test||3462||7885||test<>||keep||||||3462||7885||<>test1||keep-me-too!||1:1||test||3462||||test
```

It can be seen as 3 different strings which are separated by `<>`:

```
test1||keep-me||1:1||test||3462||7885||test

||keep||||||3462||7885||

test1||keep-me-too!||1:1||test||3462||||test
```

And I want to extract:

```
array('keep-me', 'keep', 'keep-me-too!')
```

---

**Notes**

I have tried doing this with `preg_match` but look-behind doesn't like searching for non-fixed length strings.

I cannot change the data. It is old data I just have to work with.

Comment: Post your attempts...

Comment: explode on `<>`, and then explode each piece on `||`?

Comment: @andrewsi It might have to be that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array = [];
$strings = explode('<>', $yourContent);
foreach ($strings as $string) {
    $array[] = explode('||', $string)[1];
}
```

This uses array dereferencing introduced in PHP 5.4.

Comment: Thanks, I'll test this and report back as I have to do this on 8000 rows of data and then loop through each of the 8000 sets of results too.